# Square root of minus identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that $-I_n$ (seen as real matrix) has a square root if and only if $n$ is even (where $A$ has a square root if it exists $B$ such that $A=B^2$).
If $n$ is even I have found $B$ matrix with diagonal block:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and this works! For the converse, however, how could I proceed?

Comment: Over $\Bbb C$  every invertible matrix has a square root. So also $-I_n$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant the real case. Now I edit the text!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the real case, if $A^2 = - I_n$ with $n$ odd, taking the determinant gives
$$\mathrm{det}(A)^2 = -1$$
which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of something about spectral theorem and not the determinant...